# "Visit Meta" doesn't list new questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

I posted a question about the beta badge and it doesn't show in the list of questions on meta. It looks like it is because it sorts by newest reply and no one has replied yet. But users are far less likely to see a new question unless they routinely come to meta. Don't you think new questions should be displayed as well to help encourage discussion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for displaying on the featured require the meta question to be in the "hot" tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reply now and it's still not listed on the main site. Also, the "Design for Pro Webmasters" question was listed yesterday, before there were any answers.

Perhaps the list is only updated once every 24 hours?

Comment: Well the beta badge question is now listed, but neither this question nor the latest one is showing yet. It may be best to ask on meta.stackoverflow.com, one of the mods may have more insight.